# Midnight Commander: how to enable filter-as-you-type behavior

Tags: mc

Basically looking for a feature similar to Total Commander filter-as-you-type.

Comment: Please post this on Super User instead; it has nothing to do with solving a programming problem. I can't flag this because it has an open bounty.

Comment: This is the open ticket for it, its got some ideas how to realize it: http://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/2697

Comment: heh, I was actually the one to open that ticket. Got nothing worth-reading there.

Comment: I really miss this functionality too... There is a long way to do such thing using external panelizing. ctrl+x+! and making a find command there. But you have to spend a lot of time just pushing buttons so it isn't actually a good solution

Comment: See also [How to filter directories in Midnight Commander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681801/how-to-filter-directories-in-midnight-commander)

Answer (score 13):

Isn't the quick search suitable for your need? If i'm not wrong alt+s will show the "quick search" in Midnight Commander but can't check it right now.

Comment: Yes actually that's it, alt+s does the job.

Comment: In fact, by disabling the command line in the options, it's possible to get the same behavior as Total Commander (i.e. typing any key will jump to the relevant file/folder, without having to press alt+s first).

Comment: Yep, I'm well aware of that option. Great option it is. It doesn't, however, qualify as filter-as-you-type, but as find-as-you-type. I want only the relevant options to show, not go-to them.

Answer (score 5):

Hide command line from option menu (Options > Layout > Other Options > Command prompt). Then <kbd>Alt + S</kbd> auto show if type any char.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: For English-speaking users. It is in `Options` > `Layout` > `Other Options` > `Command prompt`.

Answer (score 1):

After pressing Alt+s, you can use the asterisk (*) sign to find the file by pattern. For example, *data finds the file "discrete_data.csv"