# How to filter directories in Midnight Commander

Tags: command-line-interface, mc

Maybe a stupid question, but how can I filter directories in Midnight Commander?

For example I have a folder with a lot of directories in it with the following naming:

```
holidays (2016)
birthdays (2016)
holidays (2015)
...
```

How can I filter like `*2015*` on directory tier?

Comment: Relevant: [Ticket #2697 feature request: Filter as you type mode](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2697)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Midnight Commander: how to enable filter-as-you-type behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389781/midnight-commander-how-to-enable-filter-as-you-type-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

You can press ctrl+s and type `*2015*`;
or if you want to search all directories by some given criteria, you can press alt+? (esc+? on Mac) and you will see search dialog:
at 'Start at' put path to the folder where you would like to search something
at file name you can put search criteria: `*2015*`

Answer (score 2):

The closest one can get to this feature at the moment is:

1. Using **quick search** by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and then typing your search pattern. The cursor will jump to the first match, but to toggle through all results that match the current pattern, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.
2. Disable `Command prompt` in `Options` -> `Layout...` (press <kbd>F9</kbd> to get to the menu bar), and when you start typing **quick search** will be instantly activated (without having to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>).
3. Try any of the workarounds in the open [Ticket #2697 feature request: Filter as you type mode](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2697)